# SQL: Aggregate counts of a related model

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database schema:

Shop 
with fields: id, address, name

Product with fields: 
id, shop_id, category(enum: clothes, furniture, electronics)

Is there a way to write an efficient query to get the information about shops so the final query would produce a summary about each shop. For example:

```
name     clothes  furniture  electronics
shop1       5        3          100
```

Answer (score 1):

use conditional aggregation:

```
select name, count(case when category='clothes' then 1 end) as clothes,
count(case when category='furniture' then 1 end) as furniture,
count(case when category='electronics' then 1 end) as electronic
from
(select name,category from shop inner join product 
on shop.id=product.shop_id)a
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Pivot` table.

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a4971/13)

**Pivot:**

> PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values
>   from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output,
>   and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining
>   column values that are wanted in the final output

**Unpivot:**

> UNPIVOT performs the opposite operation to PIVOT by rotating columns
>   of a table-valued expression into column values.

More about [Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select *
from
(
  select name, value
  from(
  select name, category
  from test t
  join shop s on s.id = t.shop_id) as s
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (category)
  ) unp
) src
pivot
(
  count(value)
  for value in ([clothes], [furniture], [electronics])
) piv
```

Comment: This is a solution for SQL Server not for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

If you know the columns that you want, I would write this as:

```
select s.name, 
       sum( (p.category = 'clothes')::int ) as clothes,
       sum( (p.category = 'furniture')::int ) as furniture,
       sum( (p.category = 'electronic')::int ) as electronic
from shop s join
     product p
     on s.id = p.shop_id
group by s.name;
```

You might also consider `crosstab()` or dynamic SQL if you do not know the columns.